# AES Managed Provider Defaults

Tags: c#, .net, encryption

We are a .net shop and have implemented a few solutions using the AesManaged provider. Now we need to exchange some data with a third party and they have proposed a solution that uses non-default settings for the AES provider.

.NET Defaults:

```
BlockSize = 128;
Mode = System.Security.Cryptography.CipherMode.CBC;
Padding = System.Security.Cryptography.PaddingMode.PKCS7;
```

Vendor proposed settings:

```
BlockSize = 128;
Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
```

My question: Are the default settings good enough? Why should we consider changing any of these settings. It should be noted that I am not sure they are using .NET so these might simply represent different system defaults.

Comment: "Are the default settings good enough?" Good enough for what? Since changing these values results in a completely different ciphertext, I imagine you'll have to use the settings that they specify if you want your data to work with their system.

Comment: John, Being that we are paying them for their services, and they are implying that any type of encryption is a "custom" solution, I think we can dictate the settings.

Comment: @Andrew - ahh, from your question it seems as though you are sending data to their system which could have different system defaults that wouldn't be changed. Knowing that you can dictate the settings on their end, what are you protecting against? I'm a little unsure why they would intentionally make the algorithm weaker by introducing the non-default ECB cipher mode. The only benefit I can think of for using that is to save CPU cycles? To see what happens to an encrypted image using the different modes, check out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation

Comment: @John, thanks. Actually they are hosting our HR Portal and then launching some local web based apps. We are passing an encrypted Employee number along with some time based threshold data. Nothing requiring ultra security but simply stuff we don't want users modifying.

Comment: Maybe the vendor is using Java on their side (ECB is the default mode in Java, though there's no reason why they couldn't configure it for CBC/CFB/OFB)

Comment: @finnw, I think the vendor was just plain incompetent. We sent them a full tech spec including all settins etc. We then sent them a copy of our entire encryption library. Finally we sent them a extremely simplified little piece of code that they were able to implment directly. We found out halfway through the endtire process that they were in fact using .NET v3.5 just like us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blocksize for AES is "non-negotiable", it's what the standard prescribes.
Mode ECB won't do anymore. Don't. 
CBC is fine, but needs padding, so you could use CFB or OFB mode, or counter mode
if random access is important. Zero-padding is only OK if the format of the plain text and/or the context determines what the effective length of the plain text is, otherwise avoid it: PKCS7 is uniquely decodable.

Answer (score 1):

The .NET default should be good enough. The vendor settings isn't more secure. [ECB seems to be less secure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.ciphermode.aspx).